# Regex pattern immediately followed by another String

Tags: regex

In the following input string

> abcd, of regex is not my cup of tea and coffee , but abcd - and efgh of JS are my whisky

I want to match `abcd - and` only.

More generally `ab.*?` followed by any number of special characters and spaces which then followed with literal `and`

I tried the following pattern `abc.*?(?!(\w))\sand` but this is matching both strings highlighted bold in the input string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern `abc.*?(?!(\w))\sand` matches too much, as `.*?` can backtrack (it matches any character) till this assertion `(?!(\w))` it true and it can match `\sand`

But it is the same as writing `abc.*?\sand` because this part is always true `(?!(\w))\s` because the next character is `\s` and therefore automatically not `\w`

---

You could use:

```
\bab\w*\W*\sand\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `ab` Match literally
- `\w*` Match optional word chars
- `\W*` Match optional non word chars
- `\sand` Match a whitespace char followed by `and`
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bB1jTm/1)

Comment: was a fault on myside I deleted my question, you already helped me

Comment: abcd, of regex is not my cup of tea and coffee , but abc'd - and efgh of JS are my whisky This string is not matched with the above the pattern why is the \W not taking the single quote

Comment: @ANOOPKUMARAYTHALA It is because it matches abc, and then `\W` will match the `'` but it can not match the `d` after it. You might do it like this https://regex101.com/r/SSsREc/1

Answer (score 0):

As simple as `abcd\W+and`.

Or `abcd(?=\W+and)` if you only want to match the textual part.